# Why is `module.config` function executed multiple times during testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using Karma + Jasmine to test my code. I've noticed that `module.config` function is executed multiple times. Does it mean that angular application is initialized multiple times? What framework does that - Karma or Jasmine? How is angular application destroyed? How often the app is reinitialized?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add into capabilities : `'maxSessions' : 1`